# Expansion with numbers in human readable format

Tags: zsh, wildcards

So, I want to play some MP3s in a console player that takes file names as inputs. I have the following files, as given by `ls -1 *` where `*` get expanded by my shell (zsh):

```
1 - Main title.mp3
10 - End title.mp3
2 - Intro.mp3 
...
```

But clearly, how I actually want them to be ordered is like so:

```
1 - Main title.mp3
2 - Intro.mp3 
...
10 - End title.mp3
```

What shell expansion magic do I need to make it so?

I know I could get the same thing with some clever pipes and `sort -h` but that's not really an option *because I am a lazy typist*. So, unless I wrote a small shell script to add song, I'd just rather do `nyxmms2 add /path/to/dir/*.mp3` thus why I am looking at how to do the filtering within zsh's expansion... Also, I want to know if this is possible because it applies to a lot of other situations as well -- for example, log files or revisions or ...

Comment: Could explain why the sort method isn't an option? Just curious. What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: Done: In a nut shell, I am lazy and cannot be bothered with typing | sort -n all the time I add things ... ^_~

Comment: make it an alias then: `alias lss="ls | sort -h"`. Make it part of your environment so it's always there.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `n` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
print -lr -- *.mp3(n)
```

You can change the default sort order by setting the [`numeric_glob_sort`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NUMERIC_005fGLOB_005fSORT) option.

```
setopt numeric_glob_sort
print -lr -- *.mp3
```

If you need lexicographic order for one pattern while `numeric_glob_sort` may be in effect, negate the `n` glob qualifier.

```
print -lr -- *(^n)
```

Comment: Though probably not an issue to the OP, it should be noted that the `n` flag only understands positive integer decimal numbers (no negative, no floats, no k/M/G/T... suffices like `sort -h` does, no hex, and numbers with leading 0s are considered as decimal, not octal)

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to run the output of `ls` through the command `sort` to control how the output is displayed.

You can use the `-h` (aka. `--human-numeric-sort`) which sorts things in human readable form.

```
$ ls | sort -h
1 - Main title.mp3
2 - Main title.mp3
10 - Main title.mp3
```

#### EDIT #1 - addressing OP's comment

The above can be wrapped into an alias like so:

```
$ alias lss="ls | sort -h"
```

Running the above command would then be reduced to this:

```
$ lss
1 - Main title.mp3
2 - Main title.mp3
10 - Main title.mp3
```

#### References

- [sort man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort)
- [Tutorial on the basics of using sort](http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/sort-files-like-a-master-with-the-linux-sort-command-bash/)

Comment: As I said in the question, I was hoping not to have to use pipes and sort but for some magic with zsh that would allow it to do that for me when it expands `*`.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the sort order in `zsh` globbing (see [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73855/22565)), but `ls` will sort its arguments anyway, and by default lexicographically.

If your `ls` is the GNU `ls`, you can use the `-v` option to sort numerically:

```
ls -1v
```

Or:

```
ls -1vd -- *
```

It's not equivalent to `sort -h` because `sort -h` is to sort things like the output of `du -h`, that is where `1.12G` is bigger than `999M`, while `ls -v` and `zsh`'s `(n)` globbing qualifiers are geared towards sorting things like version numbers (where 1.20 is greater than 1.4 for instance).

If you do want a globbing that understand those suffices, you'd need to write a zsh sort function for that.

With zsh, you can define glob sorting order with a function and use it as `*(o+that-function)`. `that-function` takes the filename to sort in the `$REPLY` variable and should return into that same variable, something that `zsh` can then sort lexicographically (or numerically if `n` is also provided).

Something like:

```
h() {
  local -A x
  local match
  setopt localoptions extendedglob
  x=(k 1 K 1 M 2 G 3 T 4 P 5 E 6)
  REPLY=${REPLY//(#b)((|[0-9]#.)[0-9]##)([${(kj::)x}])/$((match[1]*2**$x[$match[3]]0))}
}
```

would replaces all the 1.1G to their value (1181116006.4).

Which you can then use as:

```
ls -1Ud -- *(no+h)
```

(`-U` being the GNU `ls` option to tell `ls` *not* to sort its arguments).

That won't work well however with numbers with a fractional part as it would sort `1.20` after `1.3` for instance:

```
$ ls
1.20  1.3  3.1G  500M
$ ls -v1Ud -- *(no+h)
1.3
1.20
500M
3.1G
```

For something that would sort all sorts of decimal floating numbers with optional suffices (like -1e20M, 1E-20, 100k, 3000M), because `zsh` can only sort lexicographically or numerically limited to positive decimal integers, we'd need a function to convert those into either strings that sort lexicographically in the same order, or positive decimal integers that sort numerically in the same order.

`zsh` does floating point and decimal arithmetic with 64bit numbers where available, so we could apply a floating point function that turns those numbers (or at least the range supported by `zsh` floats) into an integer from 0 to 2<sup>63</sup>. Using the logarithm function could be an option. Something like:

```
zmodload zsh/mathfunc
h() {
  local -A x
  local match v
  setopt localoptions extendedglob
  x=(k 1 K 1 M 2 G 3 T 4 P 5 E 6 Z 7 Y 8)
  REPLY=${REPLY//(#b)([-+]|)(([0-9]#.|)[0-9]##([eE]([-+]|)[0-9]##|))\
([${(kj::)x}]|)/[$(([#10]1e15*(1500+ $match[1](745+log((v=$match[2]\
${${match[2]##*[Ee.]*}:+.}*2.**$x[$match[6]]0)==0?2.48e-324:v)))))]}
}
```

To be used as:

```
print -rl -- *(no+h)
```

Or, to fall back to numerical sorting to differentiate 100000000000000001 and 100000000000000002 for instance (which have same logarithm with `zsh` float precision):

```
print -rl -- *(noe:h:on)
```

Then, we get something even better than `sort -h`:

```
$ ls | sort -h
-4
-3
+20
a2
b1
b10
b2
1e-20Y
1e3
1.20
1.3
3
20
999
1000 1e9
1000 900M
1001
1024
1k
12k
0.000000001G

$ print -rl -- *(noe:h:on)
-4
-3
0.000000001G
1.20
1.3
3
20
+20
999
1e3
1000 900M
1000 1e9
1001
1k
1024
1e-20Y
12k
a2
b1
b2
b10
```

Now, for your specific nyxmms2 problem, to complement Gilles' answer, I you're a lazy typist, you could also define this time a *selection* (instead of "ordering") function for music files, like:

```
m() [[ $REPLY == (#i)*.(mp3|ogg)(-.) ]]

nyxmms2 *Zep*(n+m)
```

Or use a variable:

```
m='.(#i)(mp3|ogg)(n-.)'
nyxmms2 *Zep*$~m
```

Or a global alias:

```
alias -g @m='./*.(#i)(mp3|ogg)(n-.)'
nyxmms2 @m
```

To turn on numericglobsort for `nyxmms2` only, you could do:

```
preexec() {[[ $1 = nyxmms2* ]] && setopt numericglobsort}
precmd setopt nonumericglobsort
```

Answer (score 1):

you could always use shell expansion to do this.

```
nyxmms2 add $(ls /path/to/dir/*.mp3 | sort -n)
```

since you're dealing with music you might create "playlists"

```
ls /path/to/album/or/song/*.mp3 | sort -n >> /path/to/playlist
nyxmms2 add < /path/to/playlist
```

Comment: As I said in the question, I was hoping not to have to use pipes and sort but for some magic with zsh that would allow it to do that for me when it expands `*`.

Comment: @Sardathrion why don't you want to use pipes? this is what they are for.....

Comment: Pure unadulterated laziness and the thought that there might be something within zsh that allows you to set the sorting order.

Comment: @Sardathrion there is but it wont do interpretive sort like `sort -n`... with `zsh` you could use parameter expansion to sort but it will not interpret 2 as being greater than 10 (`ls *(n)`)